# SublimeREPL not working

Tags: sublime-text-3

SublimeRepl is not working on Fedora 20 (previously working on Windows 8). I believe it's installed, as the SublimeREPL option shows up in the drop down menu; however, when I go to Tools --> SublimeREPL --> Python all the options are grayed out (note that I've had a similar problem with Package Control: shows as installed but does not allow me to browse packages).

I've tried updating the path in SublimeREPL.sublime-settings -- User to:

{
 "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/lib64/python2.7"}
}

but this has not helped. I am using sublime_text_3_build_3065_x64

Thanks